# pad string values in xslt 1.0 with leading spaces even when element is empty

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, padding, fixed-width, msxml6

I have 2 elements like this:

```
<PhoneNumber>0870 6071352</PhoneNumber>
<FaxNumber>01722 422301</FaxNumber>
```

In the output (fixed width text) both of these need to padded with leading spaces to a length of 71 characters

So I tried:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('                                                                       ', msg:ContactDetails/msg:PhoneNumber), string-length(msg:ContactDetails/msg:PhoneNumber) + 1, 71)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('                                                                       ', msg:ContactDetails/msg:FaxNumber), string-length(msg:ContactDetails/msg:FaxNumber) + 1, 71)"/>
```

but when the element is empty the *string-length* function above returns 0, so I only got what looks like 59 spaces in my output instead of 71.

I also tried:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('                                                                       ', msg:ContactDetails/msg:PhoneNumber), 12, 71)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('                                                                       ', msg:ContactDetails/msg:FaxNumber),  12, 71)"/>
```

but the same thing happens when the FaxNumber or Phonenumber elements are empty

How can I change my xsl to handle situations like this?

Comment: Check your premises. There is no reason why the formula wouldn't work with an empty string.

Comment: Have some error in example (may be in code too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[answering this old post as I stumbled on it in a search and there was no clear answer]

in the first example, this will work ONLY if your element is empty. when the length is >0 you are pulling less characters.  If the length of the field is 12 you only pull from 12 thru 71, or 59 chars

In the second you are appending 71 spaces but your substring in only pulling from char 12 thru 71.  71-12 = 59.  So again you only get 59 chars.

This is probably what you want:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('                                                                       ', msg:ContactDetails/msg:PhoneNumber), string-length(msg:ContactDetails/msg:PhoneNumber) + 1)"/>
```

The difference being leaving off the last argument on substring so you pull to the last char, not just to char 71.

Answer (score -2):

In XSLT terminology you have two distinct sources (filled elements and empty elements) so you don't have to fix it with a hard-coded function. you must fix it XSLT-style.

1) Templates - this is useful if you have not just 2 variants, but many with distinct constraints

a) Use `<xsl:apply-templates select="msg:PhoneNumber | msg:FaxNumber" mode="formatted">`

b) and two distinct templates `<xsl:template match="msg:PhoneNumber | msg:FaxNumber" mode="formatted" >` and something like that `<xsl:template match="msg:PhoneNumber[string(.)=''] | msg:FaxNumber[string(.)='']" mode="formatted" >` - second one will get higher priority

2) old-good-friend `<xsl:if />` and `<xsl:choose/>` - it's useful if emptiness is the only problem

Comment: what about removing the leading and trailing spaces from `  020 123 45678   ` then outputting the result with 71 characters even when the element is empty?

Comment: Think it's good idea to see if you can reproduce the problem before suggesting a solution.

Comment: I have and all it's ok - because our questioner have mistake in code see below